# Register app with Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

I have an app which is a website locally on my machine and all it does at the moment is send out emails through a form. I registered my app with my Gmail account (a long time ago) to be able to send emails.

What I have forgotten is how to create a new app to be registered with my Gmail account. E.g., the current app that is registered is using http://advkit.dev and I have uploaded my project so it's live and the URL has now changed to live web address. What I don't understand and can't find in my Google account settings is to register the new app with the new address so I can send out emails using my Google Gmail account.

The URL is here to show your registered apps on Gmail account is this: https://myaccount.google.com/security?utm_source=OGB#connectedapps

Answer (score 1):

Only the Google Labs are added from the Google applications settings, other applications should include a way to add themselves to the user account. I.E. Google Apps Script web application that require to access user data ask authorization to the user to access their private date on the first run.